# Get last inserted id (go + oracle)

Tags: oracle, go, oci8, sqlx

I need to insert two records in Oracle database from my go application using sqlx (https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) with go-oci8 (https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8) driver.
Second record references previous one by foreign key.
So I need to have primary key of first record (it is assigned from sequence with before insert trigger on first table) before I can insert second record.

So I experimented to get last inserted id:

```
create table t(x int primary key);
create sequence x_seq;
```

LastInsertId failed for me:

```
import(
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-oci8"
)

func main(){
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("oci8", "integr/integr@localhost:49161/xe")
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }
    sql := "insert into t values(x_seq.nextval)"
    r, err := db.Exec(sql)
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r.RowsAffected())
    fmt.Println(r.LastInsertId())
}
```

Output:

```
1 <nil>
0 LastInsertId not supported
```

Then I tried to make stored function that inserts record and returns primary key.

```
create function f(x int) return int as
v int;
begin
    insert into t values(x)
    returning x into v;
    return v;
end;
```

But I failed to find a way to get its result. PostgreSQL style select fails:

```
SQL> select f(9) from dual;
select f(9) from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
ORA-06512: at "INTEGR.F", line 1
```

And OCI8 style variable binding does not work:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-oci8"
)

func main(){
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("oci8", "integr/integr@localhost:49161/xe")
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }
    sql := sqlx.Rebind(sqlx.NAMED,"begin ? := f(?); end;")
    var a int
    _, err = db.Exec(sql, a, 333)
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(sql)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Output:

```
begin :arg1 := f(:arg2); end;
0
```

How to get last inserted ID, or how to get value from stored funcion in Go from Oracle?

Comment: either you have to use orm to get id of last inserted row(last saved object) or you can stop inserting id through trigger. Manually you can get seq.nextVal and work on it

Comment: Maybe you can fix go-oci8 driver: https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/blob/master/oci8.go?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I Don't know about go but I know about oracle return query

Same problem I had with PHP and I solve it using this query

```
insert into table (field1,field2,field3)
values (val1,val2,val3) return primaryfield_id into :xx
```

It will automatically return value in your Go variable (I guess )
please try this

Comment: I tried that too. Variable binded to :xx remains empty after a call. Looks like golang's "database/sql" package is unable to returnn values to binded variables. Only to pass them to query.

Comment: can you send me the output of your return query v?

Comment: In go output is "", as I said earlier. Binded variable remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

The variable for the returned ID must be included in the enumeration of the Exec parameters as last parameter:

```
func (c *AppController) InsertEmployee(employee *Employee) (int64, error) {

  var id int64

  insert := `insert into emp (firstName, lastName)
                    values (:firstName, :lastName) 
                        RETURNING id INTO :id`

  _, err := c.db.Exec(insert, &bundle.firstName, &bundle.lastName, &id)

  if err != nil {
    return id, err
  }

  return id, nil

}
```

The possibility to get the generated ID via the function LastInsertId() does not seem to work with Oracle.